# AngularJS error calling Paypal via PHP api

Tags: php, angularjs, paypal

Our AngularJS application gets a redirection error calling a Webserver PHP API that calls Paypal Checkout interface.

Debuging the application I received the following message in the console :
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://flyvip.com.br/app/api/DoPayment.php. The request was redirected to 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5YC93437ED462705F', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight."

The same API is called by an IOS application via a WebView and the redirection is done without any problem.

Any idea on what may be causing the error?

Thanks

Comment: Your browser is preventing a potential cross-site scripting attack. Read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting . If you need to make the call, use a proxy on your server.

Comment: Can you explain further how I could use a proxy in my server? I know the concept of proxy but not specifically on the context of a PHP Webserver.

Comment: For PHP check out: http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/

Source code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy/master/ba-simple-proxy.php